# Angular HTML Template Best Practices

Tags: html, angular

Are there best practices for writing maintainable, easy to read HTML templates, specifically in Angular?

I often have a component with multiple attributes attached to it, for example:

```
<custom-component [type]="myType" (myEvent)="onMyEvent()" *ngIf="enabled" [ngSwitch]="condition"></custom-component>
```

Is it better, when the attribute list becomes long, to split it up into multiple lines, or maybe even organize them by precedence (structural before attribute directives)?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case I would follow [Google recommendation](https://google.github.io/styleguide/htmlcssguide.html#HTML_Line-Wrapping) and format it as:

```
<custom-component [type]="myType" 
                  [ngSwitch]="condition"
                  (myEvent)="onMyEvent()" 
                  *ngIf="enabled"></custom-component>
```

Here I also grouped `[type]` and `[switch]` for ease of read.

Comment: Nice, just what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

@Andriy Well I would argue about that style too. I still prefer the "single attribute per line" approach but without this huge indentation. For components with longer tag names it looks ridiculous. So I would change your example to:

```
<custom-component
  *ngIf="enabled"
  [ngSwitch]="condition"
  [type]="myType"
  (myEvent)="onMyEvent()" 
/>
```

Self-closing tags are now supported since Angular 15. Also pay attention how I moved the `*ngIf` up because the best practice for prioritizing attributes is:

1. Template Directives (*ngIf, *ngFor)
2. Template variables (#test)
3. Input props
4. Native attributes
5. Event handlers